# Excel 2013 formula with #VALUE

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How do I add up columns `E` and `H`. A simple `=E8+H8` gives a `#VALUE!` outcome.

Note the formula in `O5`:

[image: worksheet: note the formula in O5]

Comment: Hard to find the reason, since column E is blank. Normally this error may occurs when reference is wrong ! Generally blank cell doesn't causes the error since Excel evaluate it as Zero.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of the error is that column `E` contains a formula with a null string result.

To fix the issue use the `N()` function to convert that value to a `0`:

```dart
=N(E8)+H8
```

The other possible values in `E8` that can cause the same error are:

- A function that returns one or more white-space only characters
- A literal `'` followed by any amount of white-space
- One or more literal white-space only characters

What is certain is that it is *not* blank! If that were the case, Excel would convert the value to a zero, and the formula would work.